# Azure DevOps: Insert local YAML template in remote YAML template

Tags: azure-devops

Regarding the Insertion section of this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#insertion

Is it possible to reference a local template as an inserted step(s) in a remote template.

For example, I can't seem to get something like this to work:

```
# File: jobs/build.yml (remotetemplates)

parameters:
  preBuild: []
  preTest: []
  preSign: []

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
  - script: cred-scan
  - ${{ parameters.preBuild }}
  - task: msbuild@1
  - ${{ parameters.preTest }}
  - task: vstest@2
  - ${{ parameters.preSign }}
  - script: sign

# File: .vsts.ci.yml

jobs:
- template: jobs/build.yml@remotetemplates
  parameters:
    preBuild:
    - template: templates/steps/my-local-steps.yml
```

The result is something like: `jobs/build.yml@remotetemplates: File templates/steps/my-local-steps.yml not found in repository <URL of remote repository>`

Is there another approach I can use that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Does the below explanation could solve your puzzle? If not, please leave comment with any puzzle to let us know.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT - Yes, thank you for your help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to reference a local template as an inserted step(s) in
>   a remote template.

Need sorry to say that no, you can't.

When you call one yml file from another template repos, all the template file must come from one same repos. Because the logic of template repos called in another repos is making the `template repository` is completely **independent**, only stores templates and used by other repositories. The significance of this design is to improve the reuse rate of code, called templates. Another advantage is **regulate** the templates.

So, when you use the template repository in YAML, the templates can only come from this template repository.

> Is there another approach I can use that would allow me to do this?

There has two method.

- Store this `templates/steps/my-local-steps.yml` file in your template
  repository. Then, don't need add other code. Just simply script is
  ok.

If this, there are some errors on your `.vsts.ci.yml` file.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: {projectname}/{repos name}
jobs:
  - template: jobs/build.yml@templates
    parameters:
      preBuild:
      - template: {local steps which store at your template repository}.yml
```

Refer to this doc for template reference format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#using-other-repositories

- Convert this `templates/steps/my-local-steps.yml` into script, add
  the pure script into this **insertion** YAML.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks Merlin for the detailed explanation and alternative approaches. My intention was to allow consumers of the template repository to insert their own custom tasks so option #1 doesn't fit the model I'm aiming for. Option #2 works, however for lengthy or deeply nested YAML it doesn't feel as elegant.

Comment: @poltj18 Great it could help you with this. Yeah, especially if the nest depth is 4, the YAML will look very lengthy. We just publish this template feature soon, and am initially improving this feature to achieve functionality while also meeting our code requirements, such as reducing redundancy.

Comment: @poltj18 In addition, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/541930) if you think this can also help others who has the same puzzle with you.

Answer (score 1):

Can't we use `@self`?

```
...
jobs:
- template: jobs/build.yml@remotetemplates
  parameters:
    preBuild:
    - template: templates/steps/my-local-steps.yml@self
```

I found the answer below while trying to include my local templated steps into the expansion of a remote template.

[How can I use my template in a pipeline definition that extends a template from another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609360/how-can-i-use-my-template-in-a-pipeline-definition-that-extends-a-template-from)