# How can I use my template in a pipeline definition that extends a template from another repository?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that extends a template from another repository.  That external template takes a `stageList` called `stages`.

My pipeline:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: OtherProject/OtherRepo
      ref: refs/heads/main

extends:
  template: BaseTemplate.yml@templates

  stages:
  - stage: build
    jobs:
    - job: main
      steps:
```

My steps include some localization, where I need to execute a `task` for each language.  I currently have each language manually defined as a separate task:

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build (de-DE)'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyProject.wixproj'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:Cultures="de-DE"
    ...more args, 15 lines long...
```

...repeated for each language.  Gross.

So I'd like to try to use templates for this.  But when I move the MSBuild task to another file and try

```
- template: ./templates/localizedBuild.yml
  parameters:
    language: 'de-DE'
```

then ADO gives me this error when I go to queue up a pipeline run:

> The 'stages' parameter is not a valid StageList.
> /.pipelines/MyPipeline.yml: File /templates/localizedMsi.yml not found in repository https://company.visualstudio.com/OtherProject/_git/OtherRepo

As I understand it, this is because paths to templates are calculated relative to the file doing the including... which is the `BaseTemplate.yml` file, not `MyPipeline.yml`.

Is there a way to indicate in the yml that I'm trying to reference a template in *my* repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you haven't defined your local repo as a `resources\repository` it is declared automatically as `self`

Try adding:

```
- template:/templates/localizedBuild.yml@self
```